# Unit Step Response of an Integrator

Tags: matlab, audio, python

Desinging a very basic 1st order integrator with the continous transfer function:

$H(s) = -1 / (0.001 s)$
[No zeros, one pole at origin]

I was expecting the unit step response to be positive-slope.
However in my Python code I get a negative slope.

```
num = (0 , -1)
den = (0.001 , 0)
Hs = sig.lti(num,den)
t, s = sig.step(Hs)
plt.plot(t,s)
```

Provides:

[image: A negative slope of Output Vs. time]

Comment: $H(s)$ has a negative sign, that's why.

Comment: That's the sign for more coffee needed.

Comment: I'll drink to that! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your integrator has a negative sign:

$$H(s)=-\frac{1000}{s}\tag{1}$$

That's why its step response also has a negative sign:

$$y(t)=-1000\int_{-\infty}^tu(\tau)d\tau=-1000\cdot t\cdot u(t)\tag{2}$$

where $u(t)$ is the unit step.

Comment: Man! Do we really need to post answer for a single **negative sign** ;-)))

Comment: @Fat32: One yes, otherwise it keeps popping up as unanswered, two or three, probably not :)

Comment: that's a reason i bitched on the meta about SE always regurgitating unanswered questions.  sometimes they're unanswered because the question is useless.  hopefully the OP will check-mark Matt's answer and then SE will be satisfied that it's answered and we all can move on.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Yes, what we *can* do about it is suggesting to close bad questions, and answer all others.